# Django-background-tasks : tasks being randomly locked and never unlocked

Tags: django, python-3.x, cron, ubuntu-18.04

I am using the django-background-tasks 1.2.0 on Ubuntu 18.04 and Im running it with a cronjob. Is it possible that my cronjob somehow starts the tasks right before it is refreshed and then it gets stuck ?
It could be one or many stuck tasks at the same moment, depending on how many pending there are.

Cronjob:

```
* * * * * /project/manage.py process_tasks --duration=59 --sleep=2
```

settings.py

```
BACKGROUND_TASK_RUN_ASYNC = True
BACKGROUND_TASK_ASYNC_THREADS = 4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After six months of extensive testing the only way I don't get any stuck tasks is by running two parallel cron jobs that overlap each other and at the moment of refresh there is always one running. I ve tried with 1 running for longer period (3600 seconds) but i got to the same problem.

```
1 * * * * /project/manage.py process_tasks --duration=3600 --sleep=2
24 * * * * /project/manage.py process_tasks --duration=3600 --sleep=2
```

I hope it ll help you guys as well.